# How print radio button value in button onpressed in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have two radio button with value 50 and 100. What I want to do is display the value of active radio button every time I pressed the proceed button.

```
    int selectedRadio;
      @override
    void initState(){
      super.initState();
      selectedRadio = 0;
    }
    void setSelectedRadio(int val){
      setState(() {
       selectedRadio = val;

      });
    }

    void buttonpressed(){
      print(selectedRadio);
    }

     children: <Widget>[
               Text("4 Wheels(100)"),
               Radio(
                value: 100,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                onChanged:(val) {
                    setSelectedRadio(val);
                },
               ),
               Text("2 Wheels(50)"),
               Radio(
                 value: 50,
                 groupValue: selectedRadio,
                 activeColor: Colors.blue,
                 onChanged:(val) {
                   setSelectedRadio(val);
                 },
               ),

              RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: buttonpressed,
                    child: new Text(
                      "print radio button value",
                     ), 
                   ),

            ]
```

Comment: What is the issue? Where are you stuck at?  print(selectedRadio) not working?

Comment: it won't print using that

Comment: it suppose to print the value of the radio button

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works fine.

To solve your problem try to do these things:

- Check if you're not setting some value to `selectedRadio` inside
  `build()`
- In your project directory try running `flutter clean`
- Instead of using hot-reload restart / reinstall the app